# Problems validating String

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm currently doing a kata on codewars, where I have to check if a String is valid.

A String is valid when all the Parenthesis used are correct (e.g. "(())" -> correct ")())" -> not correct)

And I had the idea to make the method recursive, by using following code:

```
import re

def doMagic(s, n):
    
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    if n < 0:
        return n
    if len(s) == 1:
        if s[0] == '(':
            n += 1
        elif s[0] == ')':
            n -= 1
            
        return n
    
    if s[0] == '(':
        n += 1
    elif s[0] == ')':
        n -= 1
    
    n += doMagic(s[1:], n)
    print(n)
    return n

def valid_parentheses(string):
    string = re.sub("[^()]", "", string)
    openPars = 0
    
    return True if doMagic(string, openPars) == 0 else False
```

(I filter the String because there can be random characters in it)

The code works for the most part, except for the input "()()".

Does anybody see why it won't work for that specific case?

Comment: You should try debugging it and stepping through the code.  inspect the relevant variables and see when they start giving unexpected values.

Comment: I can't find an input the returns `True` for example: `valid_parentheses("(())")` -> `False`. What am I missing?

Comment: When `len(s) == 0` you should return `n`, not `0`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer interestingly enough, on codewars all the test-cases are either false or an empty String. I defenitly messed up somewhere, but I can't find where I messed up.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.